# How can you view npm packages on a website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-visualization, deck.gl

I've been trying to get a specific Node.js package made by Uber working. I'm new to Node js, but these are the steps I followed to get the code:

1. Cloned their [repo](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl)
2. ran npm install
3. ran npm start

I don't understand how I can view this website, though. It seems to have worked in terms of starting the package, but now where do I go to view this website? Generally there should be an html file, right? I don't see one.

Comment: Are you looking to use there node package.??

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the node package using the following command to use it in your project.

```
npm install --save deck.gl luma.gl
```

For example if your are working with React JS . You can write the code in this way.

```
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import DeckGL from 'deck.gl/react';
import {ScatterplotLayer, Viewport} from 'deck.gl';

const data = [];
const viewport = new Viewport();

return (
  <MapGL>
    <DeckGL
      viewport={viewport}
      layers={[new ScatterplotLayer({data})]}
    />
  </MapGL>
);
```

Please refer this links:

Getting Started: http://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/overview/getting-started

Usage with React: http://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/usage/using-with-react

Here html is virtual dom which is in JSX syntax.

Comment: when I do this, I get a compiler error with babel: 'return' outside of function

Comment: I too didn't tried this @yunbekyunbek. If possible please try the other example in 2nd link which i have provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `start` script, you can see it just goes, install and then launch a standalone example, not the actual website hosted on github pages.

```bash
(cd examples/layer-browser && (path-exists node_modules || npm i) && npm run start-local)
```

To checkout the code and dependencies of the website, go in the [demo directory](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/tree/master/demo). While in this folder, you can `npm install` to get the website dependencies, export the global `MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` env variable with a valid mapbox token (you can get one free on the [MapBox website](https://www.mapbox.com)) and finally run `npm start`.

It will open a browser on `http://localhost:3000` and you can start playing around.

<sub>Disclaimer: I work for Uber in the Data Visualization team responsible of deck.gl.</sub>